# Better understanding histograms in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot, you can create a histogram like

```
binwidth=#whatever#
set boxwidth binwidth
bin(x,width)=width*round(x/width)
plot "gaussian.data" u (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0/10000) smooth freq w boxes
```

Here, I am interested in a probability histogram, hence the `1.0/10000`.

I have spend a lot of time reading the gnuplot documentation on `using` and what I understand is that I am telling gnuplot to plot data from `gaussian.data` using certain values for the `x` and `y`. In fact, when I open the data file associated with the `plot` command (achieved through making a temporary file), I see that the y values are 1/10000, as expected. But then, the `x` and `y` values change. It seems like there's something dynamic about it. I do not quite understand this behavior of `using`. Could anyone please guide me?

Comment: This might sound like a very crazy idea, but look into the gnuplot documentation. The function s(x) uses the standard C *serial evaluation operator* ",".

Comment: I have read the documentation many times, but still do not quite understand how `using` interprets `expressions`. If you could please elaborate, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dont understand your question. *using 1:2* reads the value pairs from column 1 and 2 for every line in your file. *using 1:(2)* returns the y-value 2 for every x-value read from column 1 in your file. Whatever is in brackets () is an expression and get evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else would like further explanation.
http://psy.swansea.ac.uk/staff/carter/gnuplot/gnuplot_frequency.htm